# In Vitest and Nuxt 3 I want to test my component props, but I get an undefined reading props

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vitest

**This is my test**

```
import  Intro  from '../components/Intro.vue';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { test, expect} from "vitest";

test('Intro',  () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Intro, {props: {intro_title: 'Hello'}});
    expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('Hello');
  }
);
```

**Thats my component**

```
const props = defineProps(["introImage", "introTitle", "introText"]);
const imageUrl = computed(() => `/image/${props.introImage}`);
const backgroundImageUrl = computed(() => `url("${imageUrl.value}")`);
</script>

<template>
  <section class="intro" :style="{ 'background-image': backgroundImageUrl }">
    <div class="intro-inner">
      <h2 class="intro-title">{{ props.introTitle }}</h2>
      <p class="intro-content">{{ props.introText }}</p>
      <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

**That is the Fail message**

```
Proxy._sfc_render components/Intro.vue:10:40
      8|   <section class="intro" :style="{ 'background-image': backgroundImageUrl }">
      9|     <div class="intro-inner">
     10|       <h2 class="intro-title">{{ props.introTitle }}</h2>
       |                                        ^
     11|       <p class="intro-content">{{ props.introText }}</p>
     12|       <div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

I have read many tutorials and tried them out, but unfortunately none of the examples fit my test case.

Comment: It might be because you've defined a prop on the component `introTitle`, but then the test is passing a prop `intro_title`.  These are different names and therefore different props and would result in an error.

Comment: @yoduh thanks for answering me.  I figured out that vitest is not yet ready for component tests with nuxt 3
and  I tried both `intro_title` & `introTitle`

Comment: for dumb components it will work